# Cannot construct instance of `kotlin.coroutines.Continuation`

Tags: kotlin, websocket, jackson, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Kotlin Spring boot project (Kotlin 1.9.0, Java 17) with some regular endpoints controller and one websocket controller.
I'm using Kotlin coroutines.
When I call endpoints everything works fine. But, when I connect to websocket and try to send a message to an endpoint I get exception:
`org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of` `kotlin.coroutines.Continuation` `(no Creators, like default constructor, exist)...`

I found that on `suspend` functions Kotlin is adding `Continuation` as a param and that probably causes a problem. But, why it works on regular endpoints and not on websocket?
My websocket endpoint looks like:

```
@Controller
class WebSocketController(private val processFacade: ProcessFacade) {

    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @MessageMapping("/ws")
    @SendTo("/topic/test")
    suspend fun processOperation(@RequestBody processRequest: ProcessRequest): ProcessResponse {
        return processFacade.processOperation(processRequest)
    }

}
```

Regular controller which works:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/process/")
class ProcessController(val processFacade: ProcessFacade) {

@PostMapping("/do-something")
    suspend fun processData(@RequestBody data: ProcessDataRequest): ProcessDataResponse {
        return processFacade.doSomething(data)
    }
...
```

I'm using Maven.
`jackson-module-kotlin` is 2.15.2

Comment: It looks like Spring doesn't detect/support the suspending function correctly and it tries to invoke it as a regular function. Could you add a working function for comparison?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using non webflux Spring dependencies? I think the integration of Spring with coroutines comes with WebFlux (e.g. `spring-boot-starter-webflux`). See part 4 here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-webflux-kotlin-rsocket/

Comment: @Joffrey I was actually using that guide to start using coroutines in my project so I have all dependencies from there. Just, instead of rSocket I used regular webSocket. broot, I added working controller.

Comment: Do you have the jackson-module-kotlin in your build environment, like Maven or Gradle? Jackson needs that to work with Kotlin classes, like data classes.

Comment: @Tom of course. It is working on regular endpoints. But not on the websocket controller.